# Converting Flash File to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have flash file(.fla), using Adobe Animate converted the same to HTML. Few code has been commented out while conversion. Need to identify java script equivalent syntax/piece of code for commented Actionscript. Following is the sample commented action script.

```js
dashboard_btn.onRelease = function() {           
    ExternalInterface.call("Main.getInstance().FlashDecision","DASHBOARD");          
    gotoAndStop("DASHBOARD");
}
```

How to replace onRelease and ExternalInterface.call?

For Example, gotoAndStop("DASHBOARD"); //ActionScript, can be converted to this.gotoAndStop("DASHBOARD"); //Javascript

Comment: Don't negative mark my question, if you are not clear leave a comment. So that i can update my question. By negative marking how come i will now what i have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"How to replace `onRelease` and `ExternalInterface.call?`"*

**(1)** For `onRelease` you can use HTML's [**mouseup**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) event:

So the AS3 code:

```
dashboard_btn.onRelease = function()
```

In Javascript it becomes something like... 
(where **div** is the **container**, similar to Flash's MovieClip/Sprite containers):

```
<div id="dashboard_btn" onmouseup="someFunctionName();">
<img src="img_of_button.png" width="80" height="30">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function someFunctionName()
{
    //do what need when user's finger leaves a mouse button (release)
    alert("finger was released from button");
}

</script>
```

**(2)** There is no `ExternalInterface.call` in HTML code. That is for the SWF to communicate with its container (eg: calling a function of Javascript if SWF is contained inside an HTML document). IF you're converting to Javascript then your code is already **inside the container** (no need for `externalInterface` to exist at this point). Just manually call the Javascript function when needed.

If your code **truly** contains some JS function called `gotoAndStop` then use it, or else you could manually achieve same thing by showing content of "DASHBOARD" frame. The content could be provided by creating some HTML string and then using `appendChild` or `innerHTML` to update a `<div>` container with that HTML.

You could extended the above code into logic like this:

```
function someFunctionName()
{
    //# do what need when user's finger leaves a mouse button (release)
    alert("finger was released from button");

    //# if such Function exists in your code
    this.gotoAndStop("DASHBOARD");

    //# or else run some other Function manually
    FlashDecision("DASHBOARD");
}

function FlashDecision( input_txt )
{
    alert("Show content here of frame labeled : " +  input_txt); //where input_txt is "DASHBOARD"...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, After analysis found that Adobe Animate converted JavaScript file is depending on CreateJS library. Using CreateJS syntax and event handlers able to achieve the desired result.